# windows event log forwarding permission

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I am trying to set up an event log collector server in a Domain.

I flowed the steps described here: http://zenshaze.com/wp/?p=57

I have added the NETWORK SERVICE to the Event Log Readers group to allow WinRM to read the event logs.
In the source computer I am getting the following error in the 
Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Eventlog-ForwardingPlugin  logs
"The subscription *name* can not be created. The error code is 5004."

I tried restarting the WinRM services, that didn't help.

In the link it states that this error occurs because NETWORK SERVICE was not in the *Event Log Readers*  group when the computer was started and a reboot should fix it, but I would like to avoid reboot because that means rebooting my DC as well. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restart is needed because WinRM is run inside an existing svchost process.

If we run `Sc config WinRM type= own` and restart WinRm service it will create a new svchost process and a restart can be avoided.